# For-each loop unable to process all strings

Tags: powershell, loops

I am trying to genrate URLs using a bunch of strings and an anchor URL

strings in s.txt are

123

234

345

anchor URL is https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?qs=

The code I am using

```
$ur = gc C:\temp\s.txt
foreach($u in $ur) {
$test = invoke-webrequest -uri "https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?qs=$u"  -UseDefaultCredentials
}
$test
```

but it returns data only for

```
https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?qs=345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you **reassign** `$test` each time within your loop. I suggest this solution:

```
$test = 'https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?{0}' -f ((C:\temp\s.txt) -join '&')
```

---

You edited your question. This is probably what you are looking for. Please notice the `+=` operator to concat the results:

```
$result = @()
Get-Content C:\temp\s.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $result += invoke-webrequest -uri "https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?qs=$($_)"
}
```

Comment: Ah, now I got you. You want the URL returned multiple times (each with s= the actual record?)

Comment: I have tested what you gave, prints "https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?123 234 345" instead of separate URLs

yes @Martin

Comment: it fails except for just one string in s.txt, just like in original case; I also need to add -usedefaultcredentials for invoke-command. :(
    
`Method invocation failed because 
[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject] does not contain a 
method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:2 char:104
+ ... https://testurl.com/prod/hostdetails.php?qs=$($_)" -UseD ...
+                                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], Runti 
   meException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound `

Comment: You are right, I forgot to declare it. I adopt my answer.

Comment: Would you please mind giving a little insight into what was done here? TQ

Comment: We have to declare with `$result = @()` that `$result` is an object array. This will allow us to add the Invoke-WebRequest response to the array using the `+=` operator. If we don't declare `$result`, the type of `$result` would be HtmlWebResponseObject (instead of object[]) which doesn't support the `+=` operator